# Expressing data set with behaviour

Tags: c#

I have a small and static data set (about 500 entries, that are defined at compilation time and cannot change). However, each entry may have a different (possibly unique) behaviour. What's the best approach to represent this data?

For a bit more of context, I'm making a game, and need to store data about monsters, items/equipment and abilities. All data of the same kind has some shared characteristics and behaviour, but may differ in some other characteristics and/or behaviour. A monster will always have a name and level, and will drop loot usually the same way, but the "AI" it uses to select its next ability or what loot it will drop are almost unique.

The solutions I've got so far are:

- Hardcode each entry as a class extending the base of its kind (`public class WoodenSword : Sword`, Item -> Equipment -> Weapon -> Sword -> WoodenSword)
- Hardcode the different behaviours and have a data set file pointing to the used behaviour (`public class WeaponApplyingSlow : IWeaponBehaviour`)
- Have some scripts (NLua or IronPython) inside my data set file, using the scripts to define behaviour without hardcoding

Which one is the best approach, between these three or possible another? Considering primarily writability and maintainability (executing an external script definitely isn't a noticeable performance hit for a game). I'm leaning towards the script approach, because writing ~500 classes doesn't seem right, but maybe there's another solution I can't think of.

Comment: A class is that - a class. If the only difference between a wooden club and a metal sword is the swing time and damage done, they'll both fit perfectly in the class `WieldedMeleeWeapon` or whatever.

Comment: But a sword that apply slow effects is really different than one that doesn't - it isn't a simple property changing, but rather a method.

Comment: If the behaviours are things like weapons having "slows enemy", "paralyzes enemy", etc. then I'd stick on a list of enum values that say what behaviour it has and then another class that is in charge of implementing those effects then uses that list of enums to determine what it can do.

Comment: Then the sword has a chance to apply a `SlowingEffect` to the target of the attack in which it was used. A `Weapon` (or even `Item`, any way the base class) can have a `List<Effect>` of effects that it can apply...

Comment: Yeah, I can see it seems obvious at glance. But the effects can be really unique, like only one item in 200 that returns damage when you take damage on something like that. You're suggesting I use the second approach, hardcoding the 200 or so behaviours and pointing them in the file, right?

Comment: I should also add that you might need to classify these behaviours in more detail since a monster won't have a slowing effect in the same way as a sword but perhaps it can cast a slowing spell. Its quite a complex design decision you have here. In general you want to have few classes and then metadata that can be loaded from somewhere to describe them. Think about a character sheet for a game. It doesn't have the behaviours themselves on it, it has the names that then refer to the rulebook for what the actual effect is. All characters can thus use the same character sheet.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much number 2. Though I am not sure I follow what you mean by 3. Your tag implies you are writing a c# program so I'm not sure where your LUA or Python would be running and why putting scripts in a different language helps the lack of hardcoding.

Comment: Also bear in mind that you can have families of effects. A shield that reflects all damage is the same behaviour as a shield that reflects half damage except for the coefficient of reflection. An ice sword and a fire sword are the same except for a "damage type" property, etc. You may still end up with 200 classes but you might find that by grouping common behaviours you can reduce it to a lot less.

Comment: If I have a file containing the data, a XML file more specifically, it can have a field where the data is a script to be executed under a certain condition (when you deal damage, you do something). This way, the main (C#) program doesn't concern at all about which different behaviours each equipment or monster may have, it just tells the script to execute.

Comment: @Mephy: wouldn't the effects executing need to change stuff the c# program knows about? For example the slowing sword when it hits an orc will tell the orc it is slowed. Is this not a fact that would controlled by the c# program so your effect code would need to be able to interact with the c# programs objects? Or is your architecture much more complicated than I am anticipating?

Comment: The script can still have parameters, namely the user and the targets. This way the script can change stuff in the program, but the program didn't care about those (and can still raise events, thus calling other scripts, out of the method calls the script did).